# How to sort pandas dataframe in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sorting

I have a dataframe like this :

```
        Date          Price
0 2021-02-12 00:00:00 50
1 2021-02-11 00:00:00 2
2 2021-02-10 00:00:00 40.4
3 2021-02-09 00:00:00 775.6
4 2021-02-08 00:00:00 1000.2
5 2021-02-07 00:00:00 500
```

Columns' types with print(df.dtypes) :

```
Date         datetime64[ns]
Price               float64
```

Expected Output :

```
        Date          Price
0 2021-02-07 00:00:00 500
1 2021-02-08 00:00:00 1000.2
2 2021-02-09 00:00:00 775.6
3 2021-02-10 00:00:00 40.4
4 2021-02-11 00:00:00 2
5 2021-02-12 00:00:00 50
```

I have a dataframe like df. When I do :

```
df = df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

But nothing happen even by adding ascending = True or False.

Could you give the way pls to order this dataframe as above ?

If possible can you give the 2 possibilites like ordering by index and date but I'm looking to order by ascending date directly without touching to the index.

**EDIT for more clarity :**

```
# Converted list of dictionaries to a Dataframe
extracted_data_List_DataFrames = [pd.DataFrame(x) for x in extracted_data_List]

# Convert string to their respectiv types
for dfs in extracted_data_List_DataFrames:
    dfs['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs['Date'])
    dfs['Price'] = dfs['Price'].astype('float64')

    # Sort dataframes by 'Date'
    dfs = dfs.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=False)

print(extracted_data_List_DataFrames)
```

You have my code above. I'm not able to make the sort method to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is if modify values in loop there is no change if original list, you can assign ouput to original list of DataFrames like:

```
for i, dfs in enumerate(extracted_data_List_DataFrames):
    dfs['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs['Date'])
    dfs['Price'] = dfs['Price'].astype('float64')

    # Sort dataframes by 'Date'
    dfs = dfs.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=False)
    extracted_data_List_DataFrames[i] = dfs
```

Another idea is use `inplace=True`:

```
for dfs in extracted_data_List_DataFrames:
    dfs['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs['Date'])
    dfs['Price'] = dfs['Price'].astype('float64')

    # Sort dataframes by 'Date'
    dfs.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working well. I saw on some other post that inplace will be deprecated is that right ?

Comment: @LuckyFr - Yes, it should be, so add first alternative without `inplace=True`. But it is still used of many people (inplace) so only [suggestion yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) for deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`sort_values()` sorts the data in ascending order by default. You are interested in `.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=['Price'])

df['Date'] = [pd.to_datetime(f"2021-02-{str(x).zfill(2)}") for x in range(1, 11)]

df.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: doesn't work otherwise I would not ask the question. Thank you

Comment: Hmm, which panda version do you have? The above works with version `1.2.2`.